# Is it possible to cut the dependency chain in Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile (simplified):

```
# how to specify an install target that
# (a) installs the requirements if (and only if) any .txt file has changed but
# (b) without triggering recompilation if any *.in file has changed?

#install: ???
#   ???

# this may trigger recompilation
install1: requirements/*.txt
    for reqs in requirements/*.txt; do pip install -r $$reqs; done
    pip freeze > install1

# this always triggers installation even if requirements/*txt have not been modified
install2: 
    touch requirements/*.txt
    make install1

# compile requirements.in to requirements.txt
compile: requirements/*.txt

requirements/%.txt: requirements/%.in 
    pip-compile --upgrade --no-annotate $<
```

- `make compile` (re)compiles any modified `.in` file into the respective `.txt`.
- `make install` should (re)install the requirements from the `.txt` file(s) whenever any of them changes, but should ignore changes to `.in` files that would trigger a recompilation. Neither `install1` nor `install2` targets above satisfy both these criteria. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I don't think that make is able to work on effectively two ..ermmm.. independent dependency trees, at least not if they are statically defined with pattern rules. There is no way to tell which rule should be part of which tree. You could include a different set of depenency declarations for each of the main targets maybe.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using `pip-sync` ? This would seem to be the way to keep a virtualenv up to date with a list of requirements. I run it automatically against my project venvs as part of a sync process between machines - even when the requirements files have not changed.

Comment: @jamesc `pip-sync` is a good option if you have a mutable virtualenv that you update in place but less so for immutable environments (e.g. docker containers). Besides the `install` target above is a prerequisite for several other development tasks (e.g. running tests or migrations) which ideally wouldn't trigger `pip-sync` if nothing has changed

Comment: So you're running in docker? Could you clarify your goal in that case? It sounds like you'd like a docker layer to be recreated when requirements change - is it that kind of thing?